# How to delete content from a text file?

Tags: java, file, file-io

I would like to delete the content of a text file cause don't need its content but I need the text file for the code to work.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class code extends program{
   String [][] stock= new String[10][10];

   void show_stock()throws IOException{
       BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Isaac Sam Camilleri\\Stock\\Documents\\stock.txt"));
       for(int i=0; i<=9;i++){
           stock[i][0]=br.readLine();
           stock[0][i]=br.readLine();
       }//load stock from document
       for(int i=0;i<=9;i++){
         System.out.println(stock[i][0] + " " + stock[0][i]);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: *"..in BlueJ"* The language being dealt with is Java, and it will be the same Java code in any IDE. So don't mention (or tag) the name of the IDE, it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

*opening a file for writing and closing it sets the file-size to 0*

```
void show_stock() throws IOException {
  …
  try( FileWriter fw = new FileWriter( "C:\\Users\\Isaac Sam Camilleri\\Stock\\Documents\\stock.txt" ) ) {
  }
}
```